# What's the equivalent of app delegate file for apple watch app?

Tags: appdelegate, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to set the initial view controller for the watch app base on different type of notification received on the watch. But I don't know where's to set it.

This is the answer for an iOS app
[Multiple entry points to a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872215/multiple-entry-points-to-a-storyboard)

Comment: Well there is an accepted answer but `[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"Interface"] contexts:nil]` will change your entry point of application (If you have class for interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### watchOS 2

[`WKExtensionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015523-CH1) is the equivalent of the app delegate, where you can:

> respond to actionable notifications and manage Handoff transitions. You also use the delegate to respond to life-cycle events, such as the activation and deactivation of your app

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`, you can call `reloadRootControllersWithNames(_:contexts:)` to specify the set of pages displayed when your app launches.

You can also call `reloadRootControllersWithNames(_:contexts:)` at runtime to switch view controllers.

#### watchOS 1

There's no app delegate equivalent.

To create a custom per-notification UI, create a new Notification Interface Controller with a distinct name for the Notification Category. If you need additional customization, see [Managing a Custom Long Look Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html) in the docs.  Specifically:

> When a notification of the correct type arrives, WatchKit chooses your static or dynamic interface based on several factors. WatchKit automatically displays the static interface when a dynamic interface is not available, there is not enough power to warrant displaying the dynamic interface, or you explicitly tell WatchKit not to display the dynamic interface. In all other cases, WatchKit displays your dynamic interface. After making the choice, WatchKit loads the appropriate storyboard resources and prepares the interface as shown in Figure 16-2. The loading process for the dynamic interface is mostly the same as for your app’s other interface controllers, with the exception of processing the notification payload, which is specific to notification interface controllers.

The category name should exactly match the `category` field in your push notification JSON, like `INVITE_CATEGORY` in this example:

```
{
    "aps" :  {
        "alert" : "You’re invited!",
        "category" : "INVITE_CATEGORY",
    }
}
```

(If you're using *local* notifications, not push notifications, just set the `category` property on your `UILocalNotification`.)

Apple Watch will display the notification interface controller corresponding to your category.

See also [Notification Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1).

Comment: Hi Aaron Brager, thanks for your detailed explanation for notification.  Sorry I didn't specify clearly enough that I set the initial view controller of the apple watch app not the notification view controller. Any ideas?

Comment: I've posted a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846155/how-to-launch-different-screen-of-apple-watch-app-from-different-notification

Comment: You must edit your answer https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015523-CH1

Answer (score 0):

In WatchKit 2 there is an extension delegate.

From [watchOS 2 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html)

> In watchOS 2, your WatchKit extension has an extension object and corresponding delegate object to manage behavior that is central to your app. The WKExtension object is a shared object that is available whenever your Watch app runs. The extension object has an associated delegate object that conforms to the WKExtensionDelegate protocol.